# Replace value based on a corresponding value but keep value if criteria not met

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, dataframe, apply

Given the following dataframe,

**INPUT df:**

| Cost_centre | Pool_costs |
| --- | --- |
| 90272 | A |
| 92705 | A |
| 98754 | A |
| 91350 | A |

Replace Pool_costs value with 'B' given the Cost_centre value but keep the Pool_costs value if the Cost_centre value does not appear in list.

**OUTPUT df:**

| Cost_centre | Pool_costs |
| --- | --- |
| 90272 | B |
| 92705 | A |
| 98754 | A |
| 91350 | B |

**Current Code:**

This code works up until the else side of lambda; finding the Pool_costs value again is the hard part.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Cost_centre': [90272, 92705, 98754, 91350],
                   'Pool_costs': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A']})

pool_cc = ([90272,91350])

pool_cc_set = set(pool_cc)

df['Pool_costs'] = df['Cost_centre'].apply(lambda x: 'B' if x in pool_cc_set else df['Pool_costs'])
print (df)
```

I have used the following and have found success but it gets hard to read and modify when there are a lot of cost_centre's to change.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Cost_centre': [90272, 92705, 98754, 91350],
                   'Pool_costs': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A']})

filt = df['Cost_centre'] == '90272'|df['Cost_centre'] == '91350')
df.loc[filt, 'Pool_costs'] = 'B'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC, you can use `isin`

```py
filt = df['Cost_centre'].isin([90272, 91350])
df.loc[filt, 'Pool_costs'] = 'B'
```

```
print(df)

   Cost_centre Pool_costs
0        90272          B
1        92705          A
2        98754          A
3        91350          B
```